# How to cancel required text (required this) in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

My Flutter source code has these lines to control how users updating their profile:

```
class _TwoButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const _TwoButtonWidget({
    required this.userProvider,
    required this.userNameController,
    required this.emailController,
    required this.phoneController,
    required this.aboutMeController,
    required this.addressController,
    required this.cityController,
  });

  final TextEditingController userNameController;
  final TextEditingController emailController;
  final TextEditingController phoneController;
  final TextEditingController aboutMeController;
  final TextEditingController addressController;
  final TextEditingController cityController;
  final UserProvider userProvider;
```

Look at "**cityController**": Users have to put information to a required field named City.

Now I don't want City field is a required field so users could leave it blank.

So what have I to do next? Can you share me some lines to change this attribute?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make nullable

```dart
 final TextEditingController? cityController;
```

Now you can remove `required`

```dart
class _TowButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const _TowButtonWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.userNameController,
    required this.emailController,
    required this.phoneController,
    required this.aboutMeController,
    required this.addressController,
    this.cityController,
    required this.userProvider,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final TextEditingController userNameController;
  final TextEditingController emailController;
  final TextEditingController phoneController;
  final TextEditingController aboutMeController;
  final TextEditingController addressController;
  final TextEditingController? cityController;
  final UserProvider userProvider;
```

More about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Comment: What's the code you add to my code?
Key? key,
...
: super(key: key);

Comment: Key is object used to determine widget in Flutter Widget tree. its optional but recommeded to use in Stateless widget. read more https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Remove the required key word and make city controller nullable by adding question mark.
final TextEditingController? cityController;

Comment: please, add some code and sample to your answer

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a look over one property of your class.
You have defined constructor as:

```
final TextEditingController userNameController;
const _TowButtonWidget({required this.userNameController});
```

that `userNameController` can't be null thats why your class required that property. If you want it to be null simply use:

```
//this
final TextEditingController? userNameController;

//not this
final TextEditingController userNameController;
```

now you can remove `required` from constructor.